# How to deploy flow remotly on Prefect server?

Tags: python, server, graphql, orchestration, prefect

I started working with the Prefect Orchestration tool.
My goal is to set up a server managing my automation on different other PCs and servers.
I do not fully understand the architecture of Prefect yet (with all these Agents etc.) but I managed to start a server on a remote Ubuntu environment.
To access the UI remotely I created a config.toml and added following lines:

```
[server]
endpoint = "<IPofserver>:4200/graphql"
    [server.ui]
        apollo_url = "http://<IPofserver>:4200/graphql"
[telemetry]
    [server.telemetry]
        enabled = false
```

The telemetry part is just to disable sending analysis data to Prefect.
Afterswards it was possible to accesss the UI from another PC and also to start an Agent on another PC with:

```
prefect agent local start --api "http://<IPofserver>:4200/graphql"
```

But how can I deploy flows now? A do not find an option to set their api like for the agent.
Even if I try to register a flow on the machine where the server itself is runnig I get following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prefect/core/flow.py", line
> 1726, in register
> registered_flow = client.register(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prefect/client/client.py",
> line 831, in register
> project = self.graphql(query_project).data.project  # type: ignore   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prefect/client/client.py",
> line 443, in graphql
> result = self.post(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prefect/client/client.py",
> line 398, in post
> response = self._request(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prefect/client/client.py",
> line 633, in _request
> response = self._send_request(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/prefect/client/client.py",
> line 497, in _send_request
> response = session.post(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
> 635, in post
> return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 587, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
> 695, in send
> adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line
> 792, in get_adapter
> raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}") requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters
> were found for ':4200/graphql'

Used Example Code:

```
import prefect
from prefect import task, Flow

@task
def say_hello():
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    logger.info("Hello, Cloud!")

with Flow("hello-flow") as flow:
    say_hello()

# Register the flow under the "tutorial" project
flow.register(project_name="Test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting started with Prefect, I'd recommend using Prefect 2.0 - check [this documentation page on getting started](https://orion-docs.prefect.io/getting-started/overview/) and [this one about the underlying architecture](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/what-are-the-components-of-prefect-2-0-architecture/909).

If you still need help with Prefect Server and Prefect 1.0, check [this extensive troubleshooting guide](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/troubleshooting-prefect-server-issues-list-of-resources-you-may-check/1011) and if that doesn't help, send us a message on Slack, and we'll try to help you there.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for.
Using the section "How to deploy self-hosted Server and register first flows to the Server backend?" in the troubleshooting guide, I was able to solve the problem.
I just had to create the appropriate congif.toml on my desktop PC and then I could deploy flows to the server and run them locally.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! However, how do I authenticate my client against the remote Prefect server? I could not find information in the documentation about this.

Comment: that's where you could use Prefect Cloud, server doesn't have auth for the reasons mentioned here https://discourse.prefect.io/t/why-does-prefect-2-0-doesnt-include-auth-and-rbac-features-as-part-of-the-open-source-package/741